# Site.domain keep changing to localhost:8000 all the time

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

I am running a Django based website together with a Linux, Apache and MySQL system.

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
SITE_ID = int(os.environ.get("SITE_ID", 1))
```

I have set the proper domain name through the web administration interface (and saving it afterward), but it is keep setting back to `localhost:8000` when I am restarting the Apache server.

I must have missed something, but I don't know exactly what. If somebody did encounter this problem and know the solution, I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong (thanks to a friend).

In fact, at the root of my project there is a fixture file `fixtures/initial_data.json`, which contains:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "sites.site", 
        "fields": {
            "domain": "localhost:8000",
            "name": "MyProjectName"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "sites.site", 
        "fields": {
            "domain": "mydomain.net", 
            "name": "MyProjectName"
        }
    }
]
```

And, each time I restart the web server, the fixture is installed on the server... Thus, causing this reset of the domain name.

I just had to change the `localhost:8000` by `mydomain.net` and everything went well.